# Ignore Ventura upgrade

Tags: macos, software-update, ventura

macOS Ventura has not yet been approved by my company.
How can I ignore the Ventura upgrade, yet still get minor updates for Monterey?
I know I managed to do this a couple of years ago...

Also preferably with the way to revert this once the upgrade is approved :)

Comment: Just wait? The upgrade doesn‘t install itself automatically anyway.

Comment: The company usually takes months to approve major OS upgrades.  
The upgrade icon is a little annoying 

Comment: Our school starts testing the latest Beta release long before the actual release to make sure we don't get stung by incompatibility problems. We advise our users not to upgrade until we then test the final release. There is _always_ something that needs work. Personally, I _never_ upgrade until at least the .1 or .2 update.

Comment: @nute I recommend you request that they block the update properly. My company hides updates that are not approved. I'm in a pilot group so I installed Ventura on my work computer yesterday, but most users won't see the popup because our IT department has hidden it.

Comment: @Ezekiel big corporate, not that easy 

Comment: Gotta love incompetent IT departments

Answer (score 2):

In the Software Update Syspref, there will always be a link to select to upload and install earlier macOS updates and such, by clicking the More Info under **Other updates are available**:

[image]

[image]